# How to add delete button functionality to React app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, onclick

I am new to React, and am having issues adding a way to delete items from the database. I have been trying a bunch of different things, but this is where I'm at at the moment.

Currently, I'm attempting to use a function

```
function DeleteBtn(props) {
  return (
    <span className="delete-btn" {...props} role="button" tabIndex="0">
      Delete
    </span>
  );
}
```

Combined with the button itself

```
<DeleteBtn onClick={() => this.deleteMusic(props.music._id)} />
```

and have tried adding routes for deletion in my backend server.js file, but as of right now, I have created a seperate component that I am trying to add delete functionality to. This is the entire file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    deleteMusic: function(id) {
        return axios.delete('/pieces/' + id);
    }
};
```

I am positive there are much better ways to go about doing this, but I am stuck and having difficulty finding answers in other posts.

There error I am currently getting is a TypeError within the onClick function. "Cannot read property 'deleteMusic' of undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As for the database, I am using MongoDB with Mongoose.

Within server.js on the backend, I've tried several different versions of Mongoose .remove targeting the id of the entry at hand. I have also tried a handful of different ways to delete the entry within the component itself, combined with the route on the backend, all with zero success.

EDIT: Backend server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const musicRoutes = express.Router();
const PORT = 4000;

let Music = require('./music.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/music', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully');
});

musicRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    Music.find(function(err, pieces) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(pieces);
        }
    });
});

musicRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Music.findById(id, function(err, music) {
        res.json(music);
    });
});

musicRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Music.findById(req.params.id, function(err, music) {
        if (!music) res.status(404).send('data is not found');
        else 
        music.music_description = req.body.music_description;
        music.music_composer = req.body.music_composer;
        music.music_class = req.body.music_class;
        music.music_title = req.body.music_title;

        music.save()
            .then(music => {
                res.json('Music updated!');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send('Update not possible');
            });
    });
});

musicRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {
    let music = new Music(req.body);
    music.save()
        .then(music => {
            res.status(200).json({ music: 'New music added successfully' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('Adding new music failed');    
        });
});

musicRoutes.route('/delete').delete(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Music.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.use('/pieces', musicRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on Port: ' + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you define DeleteButton component as shown below?

```
const API_URL = 'https://yourserverurl';

const DeleteButton = ({ id }) => (
  <span
    className="delete-btn"
    role="button"
    tabIndex="0"
    onClick={() => axios.delete(`${API_URL}/pieces/${id}`)}
  >
    Delete
  </span>
);
```

And you can use it like this.

Comment: Tried it, but still no luck. I'm thinking there's something I need to add in terms of routing on the back end to pair with this. Something like the findByIdAndRemove(id) method from Mongoose.

Comment: Maybe, you can post the backend code too, if you need help.

Comment: Just added it to the bottom of my post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: musicRoutes.route('/:id').delete(function(req, res) {
});

You need to add method for deletion.

Comment: That's my issue. I have tried a dozen different combinations of things between the route and the delete function/button.

Answer (score 0):

You are using delete as a route and you don't have an id parameter on that route.
So

```
musicRoutes.route('/delete').delete(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Music.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

should, either be

```
musicRoutes.route('/delete/:id').delete(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Music.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

and you should call

```
export default {
    deleteMusic: function(id) {
        return axios.delete('/pieces/delete' + id);
    }
};
```

or, you should just remove delete from your route

```
musicRoutes.route('/:id').delete(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Music.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```